How can I prove a user is present?
For some actions, one needs to ensure a user is actually present.  As an example, sudo requires you to type your password, a secret which is kept carefully by the OS.  Thus, if sudo sees the correct password, they know either the user is present or root level access has been compromised enough to leak said password.  This access is then cached for a few minutes as "close enough" to the user still being there.
Without relying on privileged user tools, is there any way for a user to demonstrate that they are present?  I'm thinking along the lines of a challenge/response where the challenge can only be unlocked by the user's password.  I'd also consider solutions involving inspecting tty's as long as a 2nd user can verify the results (i.e. not depending on information that only the user themselves can see).  I'd prefer solutions that can be done through a terminal (rather than GUI)

What are you trying to do?

I'm trying to sign a message such that the signature says "this was signed by user12345", where user credentials are managed outside of my scope.  I wish to decrease the attack surface against this.  I bring up sudo as an example because I feel they are doing similar for the same reasons by requesting a password.

By message do you mean IPC such as d-bus or do you mean message in a more colloquial sense as in a memo or letter?

You'll have to be more specific. What level of "proof"? For a court, for an HR offense, for idle curiosity,  or what? Does "is present" mean butt in chair, user keystrokes happening,  progress toward a goal, or what?

@ZenoofElea when I was writing this, I was thinking of sending a sequence of bytes over a socket.  As you bring up other options, it occurs to me that in this case they are destined for another process on the same computer, so ipc would work

@waltinator the goal is to make it difficult for a compromised process to send a particular message to a process on a different user.  I'm not sure quite where my level of proof is, other than that demonstrating proof of knowing a password or being a superuser is sufficient (because that would be enough to do a comparable action)

When using Unix sockets, one can use the SCM_CREDENTIALS option to send its  uid and gid to the server. I think d-bus authentication relies on it. See man 7 unix.
